# Google Visulisation animation a.slice is not a function

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

Please see example fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/15t87L60/

```
var options = {
      title: 'Test',
      animation: {
        duration: 300,
        easing: 'out',
        startup: true
  }
```

There is an error showing "a.slice is not a function" (firefox) or "Object doesn't support property or method 'slice'" (IE).

I undertand it's probably trying to slice on a non-array object and i've possibly narrowed it down to startup: true in the animation properties. Only because removing this do not cause the error.

Any ideas how i can retain the startup property but not have the error?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem appears to be with the column definitions

the `"label"` should be a string (wrapped in quotes `"2013"`) vs. a number (`2013`)

this --> `{"id":"","label":"2013","type":"number"}`

not --> `{"id":"","label":2013,"type":"number"}`

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: drawChart,
  packages: ['corechart']
});

function drawChart() {
  var data =new google.visualization.DataTable('{"cols":[{"id":"","label":"Age range","type":"string"},{"id":"","label":"2013","type":"number"},{"id":"","label":"2014","type":"number"},{"id":"","label":"2012","type":"number"},{"id":"","label":"2015","type":"number"},{"id":"","label":"2016","type":"number"}],"rows":[{"c":[{"v":"21-30"},{"v":89},{"v":187},{"v":0},{"v":0},{"v":0}]},{"c":[{"v":"31-40"},{"v":0},{"v":0},{"v":96},{"v":284},{"v":0}]},{"c":[{"v":"41-50"},{"v":210},{"v":0},{"v":0},{"v":0},{"v":92}]}]}');

  var options = {
    animation: {
      duration: 300,
      easing: 'out',
      startup: true
    },
    title: 'Test'
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div align="middle">
  <div id="chart_div" style="width: 600px; height: 300px;"></div>
</div>
```

**also,** recommend using the newer library...
`<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>`

according to the [release notes](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/release_notes)...

> The version of Google Charts that remains available via the `jsapi` loader is no longer being updated consistently. Please use the new gstatic loader (`loader.js`) from now on.

this will only change the `load` statement (see above snippet)